# setListAdapter sets the DatePicker list instead of my ListView in ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity, android-datepicker

Inserting a `<DatePicker>` element into my layout XML is crashing my app:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.CalendarView$WeekView

It is visible until my Cursors load, but is malformed and does not display the days in the month:

[image: Malformed DateSelector]

For the sake of demonstration, here is a sample layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is some java to go with it:

```
public class TestDatePicker extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_date_picker);

        DatePickerAdapter myAdapter = new DatePickerAdapter();
        setListAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}

class DatePickerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() { return 0; }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) { return null; }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) { return 0; }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) { return null;}
}
```

I've figured out that in this simple example, my `<DatePicker>` is messed up because `setListAdapter()` is controlling the `ListView` used within the `DatePicker` instead of the `ListView` in my XML. Placing the `DatePicker` AFTER the `ListView` resolves the issue, but this seems fragile. I'm guessing `DatePicker`'s list uses `@android:id/list` too?

Is this a bug? Am I using `setListAdapter()` incorrectly? Should I refrain from using a DatePicker within a ListActivity altogether?

Comment: What are you trying to do my friend?

Comment: Yes, DatePicker's list uses @android:id/list too, change your id.

Comment: I just want to use a `DatePicker` within my `ListActivity` without it blowing up. I can stop using `ListActivity` and make it work. I guess I was curious if ListActivities are officially incompatible with DatePickers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it indeed looks like DatePicker uses a list with the same identifier. What the Android framework developers recommend is to host the DatePicker in it's own DialogFragment(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html). Since you do not need this in a DialogFragment, I would recommend having the DatePicker in it's own Fragment (if it is supposed to be part of the display and not a dialog) and have the ListView object be part of a ListFragment and have your activity display these two fragments. This way neither one of them would interact with each other and you would still get the expected behavior.

Also on a side note, I usually use a ListActivity only when I have to display a list (and maybe a simple widget). When you have to use ViewGroups (as in DatePicker, TimePicker, etc.), it would pobably be a better idea to refrain from using the ListActivity specifically for the reason you mentioned - the inned lists of these widgets may already be using the same identifier.